# Equal spacing for Magento's nav menu?

Tags: magento-1.7, css, navigation

Hey guys so I have categories:
Round Pendants, Ellip Pendants, Bangles, Oval ID Bracelets

At the top in my Nav Menu it lists them correctly :)
How can I change the CSS so they all take up the same amount of space?

Since Bangles is the shortest in word length it also takes up the least amount of space.  I want all of the categories to take up the same amount of space for example to fit 5 categories on each row take up 20% width space.

The only problem is when I change CSS it messes up when the window is resized! Magento  has a cool way for when the window shrinks to a certain size it compacts it into a drop down menu of categories.

TLDR: What's a great way for categories in the nav menu to take up the same amount of space even when window resizes?
[image: Window is normal size]

[image: When window shrinks]

I'll be by the computer all day so feel free to ask questions for clarification and I'll respond as soon as I can! Thanks everyone!

Comment: If you don't ever want it to become a dropdown the cleanest way would be to remove the JS that causes that and control the CSS with media queries. Without seeing the code/site in question I can't really provide the code to fix it sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing css and HTML for the navigation i can't suggest a 100% right solution. May be the following will fix the problem.

Set equal width in percentage and  make the font size in **(rem - em).** with base font value in **px**.